# Cannot access settings->displays - to add a display

Tags: software-center, .desktop

I am trying to access "settings->displays" and getting the attached error.
The "settings -> displays" dialog does flashes for an instance...

Also, when I try "system tray" it works, but there is
no means to add another display.

My OS:

```
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ uname -a
Linux nov251-desktop 6.2.0-34-generic #34~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Sep  7 13:12:03 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$ sudo gnome-control-center display

(gnome-control-center:12619): dconf-WARNING **: 14:29:48.815: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

(gnome-control-center:12619): dconf-WARNING **: 14:29:49.372: failed to commit changes to dconf: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

(gnome-control-center:12619): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: 14:29:49.725: failed to connect to g-s-d: (null)

(gnome-control-center:12619): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: 14:29:49.725: failed to connect to g-s-d: (null)

(gnome-control-center:12619): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: 14:29:49.725: Failed to get session bus: Failed to execute child process “dbus-launch” (No such file or directory)

(gnome-control-center:12619): display-cc-panel-WARNING **: 14:29:49.725: Failed to contact gnome-shell: (null)
Segmentation fault
nov25-1@nov251-desktop:~$
```

Comment: Please run `gnome-control-center display` **without** `sudo`

Comment: OK, running " gnome-control-center display ", opens "settings->display"...that solves part of the issue -  now how do I add another display ? Is   "gnome-control-center" correct command / application for adding display ? I did  try few options to now avail ...